# Accessing DOM element with difference ways

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the li2 element of the DOM in the following html doc but my accessing methods are not working even I am pointing the li2 .This question is just to understand the basic DOM accessing ways.

```
<ol id="ol1">
    <li id="li1">
        <span id="span1">
            This is Text 1
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="li2">
        <span id="span2">
            This is Text 2
         </span>
    </li>
    <li id="li3">
        <span id="span3">
            This is Text 3
        </span>
    </li>
</ol>

<div id="divContainer" ></div>
```

I used the each of the following liNode for appending divContainer but it did not work.

```
window.onload= initall;

function initall(){
     var liNode = document.getElementById("li1").nextSibling; 

    //var liNode = document.getElementById("li3").previousSibling; 

    //var liNode = document.getElementsByTagName("span").item(2).parentNode.previousSibling; 

    //var liNode = document.getELementsByTagName("ol").childNodes.item(1).parentNode.childNodes.item(1).parentNode.childNodes.item(1); 

    //var liNode = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling;

    //var liNode = document.body.childNodes.item(0).lastChild.previousSibling;

    document.getElementById("divContainer").appendChild(liNode);
}
```

Comment: There's a text node between `#li1` and `#li2`. Use `for(var liNode = document.getElementById("li1").nextSibling; liNode && liNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; liNode = liNode.nextSibling);` to find the next non-text sibling. (Adding a `<li>` to a `<div>` will produce invalid HTML.)

Comment: I would recommend two things: First, check out jQuery. It's pretty good for this kind of thing. Second, use either Firefox or Chrome and use their JS consoles. Then you could do something like `console.debug(document.getElementById('li1').nextSibling);` and you would have discovered that it was a text node, which might have helped you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.nextElementSibling), as [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.nextSibling) will retrieve text nodes, including blank space.

Comment: You might want to mention the [browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html), specifically IE8.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to append the `<div>` element inside the `<li id="li2">` element. If so, you're doing it backwards. I'm not sure why you're trying to get the previous or next element instead of just getting `li2` directly, but if I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divContainer');
var liNode = document.getElementById('li2');

liNode.appendChild(div);
```

---

Or perhaps you're trying to get the contents of `li2` and put that into `divContainer`. If that's the case, then try this:     [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2ms9/)

```
var div = document.getElementById('divContainer');
var liNode = document.getElementById('li2');

// firstChild gets you the text node after the li element (because of whitespace)
// nextSibling gets the next sibling of the text node, which is the span.
var newNode = liNode.firstChild.nextSibling.clone();
newNode.id = ''; // IDs should be unique on the page

div.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: This is not answering the question, he asked: "This question is just to understand the basic DOM accessing ways", he wants to know why "document.getElementById("li1").nextSibling" is not returning  the "li2" element.

Comment: My mistake, didn't understand what was being asked. See edit. Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/s2ms9/

Answer (score 0):

This will get the element you're looking for:

```
 var liNode = document.getElementById("li1").nextSibling;
 while(liNode != null && liNode.tagName !="LI") liNode = liNode.nextSibling;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `nextSibling` is that most browsers will treat empty white-spaces or new lines as text nodes, Internet Explorer will not. That's why when you try to get the next sibling with `nextSibling` you are getting an empty text node instead of the next `<li>` element.

If your HTML code was like this:

```
<ol id="ol1">
    <li id="li1">
        <span id="span1">
            This is Text 1
        </span>
    </li><li id="li2">
        <span id="span2">
            This is Text 2
         </span>
    </li><li id="li3">
        <span id="span3">
            This is Text 3
        </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

then your javascript code would work for `nextSibling` as you have it now.

But if you don't want to change your HTML code, you can just use `nextElementSibling` which won't retrieve those text nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually i was trying to apply these way which are described on this link http://www.pageresource.com/dhtml/ryan/part4-2.html. There are also others ways in my question which i mentioned in comments.These all ways did not work for me. Thats why I was confused to manipulate the DOM elements